# Single Sign On OpenAM Java Code

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I have two applications on two sub domains (app1.example.com and app2.example.com)
I would like to have an SSO which with one authentication, I can switch between applications without authentication again.

I am using OpenAM and Java and I already have seen few java code for it but they are quite confusing. I am also super confused on OpenAM Server configuration. They seem very confusing.
Does anyone have a very simple walkthrough for me to test?

I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly you don't have 2 sub-domains. From DNS point of view you have two hosts 'app1' and 'app2' in DNS 2nd level domain 'example.com'. The tech overview for OpenSSO is still valid for OpenAM and there is quite a lot of documentation. The J2EE agents have a sample app with a nice step-by-step readme.

The default config is quite simple, or as simple as other software with comparable complexity.

-Bernhard